# Why do I get an object is not iterable error?

Tags: django

Why do I get the following error in my app

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: 'ModelNameHere' object is not iterable
```

but I don't get it when I execute it from the shell?

I just have a custom field in my form which inherits from forms.ModelForm

```
custom_serving_size = forms.ChoiceField(
    ServingSize.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'ddl'})
)
```

**EDIT**

This is my form class

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    serving_size = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ServingSize.objects.all())
```

The error happens on ServingSize.objects.all()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
custom_serving_size = forms.ChoiceField(
    ServingSize.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'ddl'})
)
```

this has to be

```
custom_serving_size = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=ServingSize.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'ddl'})
)
```

or

```
custom_serving_size = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[(obj.id, `text user sees`) for obj in ServingSize.objects.all()],
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'ddl'})
)
```

Comment: It's much better to use a `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=....)` for this case.